# Using bootstrap popover callback

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-popover

I'm currently using bootstrap popovers to add some additional fields to my form.  To format my select boxes, I need to take advantage of the popover callback, however I seem to be unable to get the callback to fire.  If you prefer to use jsfiddle, [check it out here.](https://jsfiddle.net/neanderslob/ju5cmytc/20/)  Thanks for any suggestions.

```js
$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    return $('#popover-content').html();
  },
  showCallback: function() {
    alert('called back');
  }
});
```

```css
.container {
  padding: 20px;
}
.form-control {
  width: 120px;
}
.popover {
  max-width: 400px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<div class="container">
  <h3>Bootstrap 3 Popover HTML Example</h3>
  <ul class="list-unstyled">
    <li><a data-placement="bottom" data-toggle="popover" data-container="body" data-placement="left" type="button" data-html="true" href="#" id="login"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-search" style="margin:3px 0 0 0"></span></a>
    </li>
    <div id="popover-content" class="hide">
      <form class="form-inline" role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
          <h1>My content</h1>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: When you want to call this callback function?

Comment: @itzmukeshy7 as soon as the popover is displayed.

Comment: Means you want to call the callback as the item is clicked right then why you don't bind a click event to the element instead of going to callback? is callback is necessary?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no popover option `showCallback` instead try using one of Bootstraps built in [popover events](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#popovers-events)

So for example triggering the alert when the popover is shown you would do this

```
$("[data-toggle=popover]").on('shown.bs.popover', function () {
    alert('called back');
});
```

I updated your [JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ju5cmytc/22/) for an example...

Answer (score 2):

Try this: I have added a callback function by using `prototype` of jquery.

```
var tmp = $.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show;
$.fn.popover.Constructor.prototype.show = function () {
  tmp.call(this);
  if (this.options.callback) {
    this.options.callback();
  }
}

this.$("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
  html: true,
  content: function() {
    return $('#popover-content').html();
  },
  callback: function() {
    alert('called back');
  }
});
```

Have updated in your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Bhumika107/ju5cmytc/21/).